# Diagonal lines in commutative diagrams

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Consider

```
\begin{document}

 \usepackage{tikz-cd}

 \begin{tikzcd}
  T \arrow[r, "\eta T"] \arrow[swap, d, "T \eta" red ] 
  & T^2 \arrow[d, "\mu" red] \\
  T^2 \arrow[swap, r, red, "\mu" blue]
  & T 
  \end{tikzcd}

  \end{document}
```

How can I draw a diagonal arrow from the top left node to the bottom right node? In addition, how can I draw an arrow parallel to this arrow?
I looked in the documentation for the package but could not find the answer.

Comment: `\arrow[dr, shift left]\arrow[dr, shift right]`. Which documentation did you search in? This appears on page 2. Parallel arrows appear on page 9

Comment: This documentation: http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

Comment: Also, how do I make it not an arrow, but just a plain line?

Comment: page 4 "non arrows"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, with the simplified syntax and nicer arrow tips (in my opinion…):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[ arrows={-stealth}]
  T \rar["\eta T"] \dar[swap, "T \eta" red ]\drar[shift left]\drar[shift right]%
  & T^2 \dar["\mu" red] \\
  T^2 \rar[swap, red, "\mu" blue]
  & T
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to give two different name of the two diagonal arrows ?